# producing plots within a loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, plot

The following example produces a subplot of the 3 variables below (located in a structure):

```
    clear all 

Data.S1 = struct('data1',rand(12,1),'data2',rand(12,1),'data3',rand(12,1));
Data.S2 = struct('data1',rand(12,1),'data2',rand(12,1),'data3',rand(12,1));
Data.S3 = struct('data1',rand(12,1),'data2',rand(12,1),'data3',rand(12,1));
% Data.S4 = struct('data1',rand(12,1),'data2',rand(12,1),'data3',rand(12,1));
% Data.S5 = struct('data1',rand(12,1),'data2',rand(12,1),'data3',rand(12,1));
% Data.S6 = struct('data1',rand(12,1),'data2',rand(12,1),'data3',rand(12,1));

a = fieldnames(Data);

cmap = hsv(length(a)); 

for i=1:length(fieldnames(Data));
    subplot(3,1,i)
    plot(Data.(a{i}).data1,'color',cmap(i,:));
end
```

I am wondering, if I were to uncomment the last three lines of 'Data' hence have 6 variables in total, how would I alter the loop to produce subplots of all of the data. Keeping in mind that the number of subplots in each figure should not exceed 3 (plots get too small). So, from this example I should have 2 figure windows with 3 subplots in each. I was thinking of using some kind of if statement, but would appreciate some advice on the matter.

Amended:

```
clear all 
Data.S1 = struct('data1',rand(12,1),'data2',rand(12,1),'data3',rand(12,1));
Data.S2 = struct('data1',rand(12,1),'data2',rand(12,1),'data3',rand(12,1));
Data.S3 = struct('data1',rand(12,1),'data2',rand(12,1),'data3',rand(12,1));
Data.S4 = struct('data1',rand(12,1),'data2',rand(12,1),'data3',rand(12,1));
Data.S5 = struct('data1',rand(12,1),'data2',rand(12,1),'data3',rand(12,1));
Data.S6 = struct('data1',rand(12,1),'data2',rand(12,1),'data3',rand(12,1));

a = fieldnames(Data);
figure(1)
for i=1:3;
    subplot(3,1,i);
    plot(Data.(a{i}).data1);
end
figure(2)
for i=1:3
    for ii=3:6;
        subplot(3,1,i);
        plot(Data.(a{ii}).data1);
    end
end
```

This is the outcome I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `if(mod(i,3)==1) figure; end`

Comment: if I add this line into the loop                                     for i=1:length(fieldnames(Data));
    if(mod(i,3)==1);
        figure;                                                                        
    end
    subplot(3,1,i)
    plot(Data.(a{i}).data1,'color',cmap(i,:));
end; I receive an error Error using subplot (line 310)
Index exceeds number of subplots.

Comment: That's because when i>3 you are calling subplot with a parameter larger than the maximum (3). You should use subplot(3,1,mod(3,i)+1), this way you get only [0 1 2]+1 = [1 2 3]. The same logic as within the if statement.